# List Binding is not bound against a list for XSODATA service

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana, hana-xs

I have dropdown list, this consume a xsodata service in my app SAP UI5. This service working in local mode in SAP Web IDE Rest Full, in the deploy proccess I haven't error but when I test my app deployed the dropdown list not working and I get a error in console.

```
List Binding is not bound against a list for /MyEntity
```

When I clic in the dropdown list I get this message:

```
cdm.js:68 Assertion failed: Type for filter property could not be found in metadata!
```

It's as if the service xsodata doesn't exist.

PS: This app was deployed in sap cloud foundry.

UPDATE:

My_controller.js

```
    onInit: function () {
    
    oModelHana = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("xsodata/ServiceHana.xsodata", true);
    
    this.oSelEntity = this.byId("inMyDropdown");
    this.oSelEntity.setModel(oModelHana);
}
```

And my_view.xml

```
...
<Label text="Entity"/>
<Select id="inMyDropdown" maxWidth="300rem" items="{/Entity}">
    <c:Item key="{EntityID}" text="{description}"/>
</Select>
...
```

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Odata-Service are you using?

`sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` is deprecated since UI5 1.48

So you have to decide between

```
sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel
```

and

```
sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel
```

And why don't you [define the Model directly in the manifest.json](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109)?

manifest.json

```
"dataSources": {
            "xsodataService": {
                "uri": "/xsodata/ServiceHana.xsodata/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "4.0"
                }
            },


"models": {
            
            "": {
                "dataSource": "xsodataService",
                "settings": {
                    "synchronizationMode": "None",
                    "operationMode": "Server",
                    "groupId": "$auto",
                    "autoExpandSelect" : true,
                    "earlyRequests": true,
                    "groupProperties": {
                        "default": {
                            "submit": "Auto"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```